# view stop scrolling after resizing

Tags: ios

i am having a little problem. I have a view that is 320 x 900 with a UIScrollView and constraints and everything works fine. i have a NSNotification for keyboard did show and that works fine as well (tested with NSLog). when keyboard shows i am changing my frame to 320 x 1200 and then the view stop scrolling. The app doesn't crash since i'm able to go back. i have search everywhere and i can't get to find the right answer.

here is a piece of my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

-(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification{

    NSLog(@"Keyboard is shown.");

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1200);
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1200);

}
```

Any help would be Appreciate

Thank you

Comment: Why are you changing your frame like that? And the scrollview's content is probably now smaller than the frame.

Comment: Because when the keyboard is visible i can't scroll enough to see the entire view. the bottom of the view is always hidden. so i figured if i make the view longer it will scroll further so i'll be able to see all the way down. I have tried textFieldDidBeginEditing but again if im editing one field (there is 10) i can't scroll all the way to go and select the last field. i have to "return" to hide the keyboard and then go and and select my field with i dont think is very user friendly.

Comment: No, your logic's off and the exact opposite is true -- If your keyboard's visible, you're going to want to make your scrollview shorter so it ends at the top of the keyboard and you can scroll all the way.

Comment: That make sense. I just tried to make my scroll view shorter but now even when the keyboard isn't visible i can't scroll all the way to see everything. the shorter the scroll view is the less i can see when i scroll.

Comment: "the shorter the scroll view is the less i can see when i scroll." What do you mean by this? The less on screen at once? Also, you should reset the scrollview's frame when the keyboard hides.

Comment: yes it will be reseting! when i change text field it acting weird. it all works now THANKS A LOT i have been struggling for days. but now if i select another text field it kind of mess up everything ... the view goes back up and i can't go back down. is it because my "keyboard will hide is not set yet ?" does the keyboard hide in between 2 field ?

Comment: how do i give you a + for a good answer when it's only in comment ?

Comment: Haha No worries :) I'd have to see more of your code though to understand why that other bit isn't working.

Comment: -(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    
    NSLog(@"Keyboard is hidden.");
    
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 900);
    
}

Comment: i dont know why the code is showing like that im sorry :S

Comment: My book teaches you how to shrink a scroll view when the keyboard appears and grow it again when the keyboard goes away: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_keyboard_covers_text_field Start reading where it says "Sometimes, the interface already knows how to slide"

Comment: it works just fine its just when i go from one text field to another the scroll view goes back to 900 by it self even though the keyboard is still showing

Comment: @user3481455 I think the problem is that you're using a UIKeyboardDidShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification. You should probably be consistent. Try changing UIKeyboardWillHideNotification to UIKeyboardDidHideNotification. Either that or change UIKeyboardDidShowNotification to UIKeyboardWillShowNotification. But it should be "Did" and "Did" or "Will" and "Will".

Comment: its a great advice . i did change it but that didn't make it